# How to categorize image as a 'not categorized image' by using convolutional nets

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network

In order to classify 10 type of images, I have modeled Convolutional based Sequential model by using Keras. I utilized categorical_crossentropy. My question is that although I am getting 99% accuracy on training model by including validation data, I have a problem to identify an image that does not belong to any of 10 classes. What would be the right way to do that? 
Any test image that is one of these types is being classified by my model perfectly fine. But if an image is not one of these types, I would like to classify it as a 'not categorized image', how can I do that?

Thank you very much for your support in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Make 11 classes. One of them is "non categorized" class.

Comment: Thank you very much for this idea. How can I create 11th class? Like, let us say that I have 10 illnesses class and I have categorized images for every 10 classes. In order to provide 11th class, what kind of images should I use to prepare a dataset for 11th class? In the production environment, my system should handle the variety of not categorized images such as other illnesses image or even customer driving license. They should be labeled as a not categorized image. Thank you for your support in advance.

Comment: Just take examples of these random images. Take some from the production environment. You can also try Pierre's and Mathias' approaches. Or even mix them.

Comment: Hmm, this is valuable knowledge. Thank you. My concern is that it should be really difficult to find all type of 'not-categorized-image' samples, It can be still risky to misclassify them into the regular class. @Pierre-s mentioned a good alternative like creating a separate 10 binary models for each class. But even I am not sure that what would be the other set of images in my binary classification :(

Comment: Thinking about it again, both options in the other answers are equivalent.

Comment: I am sorry if I am repeating things but in order to clarify it one more time: let us say that I am creating a model for class A. My valid, train and set is going to be like that : A : {images from A}, Not A : {Images from B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}. If my model learns to classify what is A and what is not A. Would it learn 'what is not A' based on these remaining 9 classes? My concern is, in a production environment I have another type of images from a class that was not in my training set before such as class X. Do you think that my model classifies it as if it is one of the Not A classes?

Comment: You should add these other images to your training data, to decrease the chance of errors. Possibly, your model will learn what is A from specific features in A (the more different images you have to the other classes, the more chances your model will learn exactly what makes A instead of paying attention to other features in other images).

Comment: thank you so much for your quick help. I also think the way you told me and will try and let you know whether it is doing what we are imagining.

Comment: And as I think about this problem, I'm getting convinced that my approach is the most naive one, the other two seem better.... but to be sure, only testing.

Comment: Thank you. Yep, I am going to let all you know.

Comment: I have tried with VGG including a dropout in the fully connected but it did not work how I expected. I am now trying VGG again by including dropout on both layers. Will see how it is going to be converged and keep the post updated once I have some improvements.

Comment: Yep, I think this is working. I have two classes 0 and 1. 0 belongs to my class, 1 belongs to not categorized one. And if the prob is close to 0, it's my class else it is not categorized. Hopefully, I am correct.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do as Daniel describes, otherwise you could the confidence of the predicted class and threshold it, if it is below the threshold it is "non categorized"

Comment: Hint: this case should not use the `softmax` activation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is known as "Open Set Classification" in opposition to "Closed Set Classification" (where all testing classes are known at training time). 
A technic to address your problem is to train 10 "One versus All" models. For each model, you learn if the image belong to one class (positive match) or the rest of your images (negative match). 
Using it, if a test image has a negative match for the 10 models, it will indicate that it is an unknown class.

Hoping it helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you. If I create a separate 10 binary models for each class, how can I create a set that represents the other not-categorized images for my binary classification :(?

Comment: The idea is to create 10 binary models, each answering the question "is the image part of my class". So, for each binary model, you put all the other images from your learning dataset as negative match. Thus, you will not explicitly tell what is a not-categorized image. You will just learn for each model if a new image belongs to it or to the rest of the world (including not-categorized).

Comment: I am sorry if I am repeating things but in order to clarify it one more time: let us say that I am creating a model for class A. My valid, train and set is going to be like that : A : {images from A}, Not A : {Images from B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}. If my model learns to classify what is A and what is not A. Would it learn 'what is not A' based on these remaining 9 classes. My concern is, in a production environment I have another type of images from a class that was not in my training set before such as class X. Do you think that my model classifies it as if it is one of the Not A classes?

Comment: Exactly because it will not be recognized by any 
classifier.